# PHP Java Bridge syntax for creating object with static field?

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I would like to implement this PDFBox example in PHP Java Bridge but I'm stuck on the PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD field:

How to create this in PHP Java Bridge:

```
PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
```

https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/workingwithfonts.html

```
// Create a document and add a page to it
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
document.addPage( page );

// Create a new font object selecting one of the PDF base fonts
PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;

// Start a new content stream which will "hold" the to be created content
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

// Define a text content stream using the selected font, moving the cursor and drawing the text "Hello World"
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.setFont( font, 12 );
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 100, 700 );
contentStream.drawString( "Hello World" );
contentStream.endText();

// Make sure that the content stream is closed:
contentStream.close();

// Save the results and ensure that the document is properly closed:
document.save( "Hello World.pdf");
document.close();
```

And in PHP Java Bridge

```
<?php require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");

$PDDocument= new Java("org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument");
$PDPage= new Java("org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage");

$PDDocument->addPage( $PDPage);
// Start a new content stream which will "hold" the to be created content
$PDPageContentStream= new Java("org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream",$PDDocument, $PDPage);

$PDFont= new Java("org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont");
// !!!!Stuck on the syntax to use a static field?
$PDFont= $PDFont->PDType1Font("HELVETICA");

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the jar for fonts, fontbox. Also, available for download on the PDFbox site.

https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi

```
$CourierFont = Java("org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font");
$CourierFont = $CourierFont->COURIER;
```